# SQL Server Script Generator CAST datetime values from hex

Tags: sql-server

I  need to generate insert script from SQL Server and when i am using SQL Server Script Generator it CAST datetime values from hex e.g.

```
CAST(xxxxxxxxxxxxx as dateTime)
```

How can i avoid this ? I want actual value in script

Comment: You can't disable that unfortunately; possible duplicate of [Problems with Data Script Generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824673/problems-with-data-script-generation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatly this is not possible , SQL Server internally produce hex value as DateTime value.

This hex value is logically divided into two group one is Date & other is Time.

e.g. 0x00009CEF00A25634 - hex value.

Date part :- 0x00009CEF (decimal 40175)

Time part :- 00A25634 (decimal 10638900)

If you select this hex value like,

```
select CAST (0x00009CEF00A25634 as datetime)
```

it return, 2009-12-30 09:51:03.000

I hope this answer is helpful for you.

Thanks.

Comment: So does that mean if i leave i as it is, it will insert the correct date into target table?

Comment: Yes, If you see that generated insert script then there is already CAST function . SQL Server just show hex value but it has already put hex value into CAST function so now you can use generated script for insertion which will insert real DateTime value. Let me know for further query . Thanks...!