# Export date data from sql server 2012 using generate script

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am exporting data from an existing sql server 2012 table by using the `ssms` option `database right click -> Tasks -> generate scripts`. This works fine except for date columns.

Example output:

```
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (1, 'Frank', ,CAST(0x16190B00 AS Date));
```

I Don' find a way to export date columns to a format like `2.10.2012`. I can think about adding a string column and cast the date column values as a string, but this is just a work around.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Try this tool - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/data-export-import.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Script Generator CAST datetime values from hex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081697/sql-server-script-generator-cast-datetime-values-from-hex)

Comment: Says in [this connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/745796/ssms-generate-scripts-for-data-scripts-datetime-as-binary) that it is fixed in the next major release of SQL Server (SQL Server 2014) and that it will be ported to SQL Server 2012 SP2.

Comment: Thanks Mikael for posting the link, i think this is pretty much it. Feel free to post a comment and i accept it. I think it's no duplicate because the other question dienst refer to this bug.

Comment: Thanks @Devart for posting the link for dbForge Studio. I just used it to export my data easy & fast. Really incredible tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mikael said, this is a bug which will be fixed in the next major release of SQL Server